# Explaining the metaphor in a sentence

Tags: metaphors, simile

Am I making a metaphor by saying that?  "Beirut: The Strong Lady Lives"
Can you explain this issue, please? Thanks in advanced

Comment: I've answered, but you might find [english.se] a better place to ask about rhetorical devices like metaphor.   You will need to show some effort! You should explain what you think a metaphor *is*, and why you doubt that this example is a metaphor.  This lack of effort will attract negative votes.

Comment: tbh, if you don't know it's metaphor, it could be a news report about a woman of great strength, who people had thought died in a tunnel collapse last week.

Answer (score 0):

This is a metaphor, you are saying that Beirut is a strong lady. It is also a figure of speech called "personification", you are giving human characteristics to a non-human thing.

Of course, only you can know for sure whether you are using a metaphor.

Comment: thanks a lot.I will do your suggestion